# How to update a column in sql database from c# form?

Tags: c#, sql

I have this sql statement which references a column in the datagrid, ordName

```
string qryUpdate = "UPDATE Orders SET show=1 WHERE show=0 AND ordName=" + dto.Rows[i]["ordName"].ToString();
```

but I get an error message as below

> Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '021-01072015' to data type int.

I thought that `.ToString()` would overcome this

Comment: Use query with parameters. Is the 'ordName' DateTime type?

Comment: The value is a string so must be quoted; `ordName='" + dto.Rows[i]["ordName"].ToString() + "'";`  - as suggested a parametrized query is the correct way to do this.

Comment: Alex K. Thank you for your help. It now works as it should do

Comment: Seems like ordName is an integer value, and the value you try check for '021-01072015'

Answer (score 1):

Please use a parametrized query

```
string qryUpdate ="UPDATE Orders SET show=1 WHERE show=0 AND ordName= @ordName ";
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
   SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(qryUpdate, connection);
   command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ordName", dto.Rows[i]["ordName"].ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string qryUpdate = "UPDATE Orders SET show=1 WHERE show=0 AND ordName='@orderName'";

//your command object
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@orderName", dto.Rows[i]["ordName"].ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string qryUpdate = "UPDATE Orders SET show=1 WHERE show=0 AND 
ordName= '" + dto.Rows[i]["ordName"].ToString() + "'";
```

now the update query will be

```
UPDATE Orders SET show=1 WHERE show=0 AND 
    ordName= '021-01072015'
```

Answer (score -1):

```
string qryUpdate = "UPDATE Orders SET show=1 WHERE show=0 AND ordName='" + dto.Rows[i]["ordName"].ToString()+"'";
```

Comment: Although this might be the correct code, you should add an explanation to it.

Comment: Error describe it self, that's why I have not explained.

Answer (score -1):

Please try this.

```
var  qryUpdate =string.Format("UPDATE Orders SET show={0} WHERE show={1} AND ordName='{2}' ",1,0 ,dto.Rows[i]["ordName"].ToString());
```

Comment: Why you give me down vote ??? Who ?? Please say something whats wrong in this answer.